# python - format float to decimal in pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, format, decimal

I have this code in pyQt:

`calculation = day + night
 self.label.setText(repr(calculation * 30)`

and I can see result as: 3.7446232 but I would like to see as 3.74.

Could you please point me to how to set decimal to 2. Should I use 
`.format(round(calculation * 30)` or for pyQt is different way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
self.label.setText("%.2f", % (calculation * 30))
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: Shouldn't that be "%.2f"??

Comment: Thank you gys for answer. JETM yours solution did not work in my python 3.5. Instead of yours I use self.label.setText("%.2f" % float(calculation * 30)) and works now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.lineEdit_4.setText("%.2f"%(row[3]))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)