# convert float value to str without rounding in python3

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, decimal

I am having a calculation problem.

```
main_value = 4.4789
```

Now i want to compare this value with a user input value

```
user_input = 4.5

if main_value >= user_input:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

The problem is i'm displaying the main_value in single digit precision in GUI **(4.4789 gets rounded and displayed_value = 4.5)**

so when comparison is made the display **shows 4.5 but prints NO...**

how do i solve this!!!

Should i use Decimal module (please with an example) or any other simple method is there??

Thanks!!

Comment: What GUI are you using?

Comment: PyQt, .ui file from QtDesigner and importing it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814941/python-format-float-to-decimal-in-pyqt

Comment: But that method rounds the value.. I dont want to round the value.. Display as it is with 1 decimal places..

Comment: If you stay under the automatic round made by Python on float, you can use `str(f)[:str(f).index('.')+2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s[:s.index('.')+1+n]
```

where `s` is your string representing your float and `n` the number of digit you want to keep after the `.`